# SQL execution #1054

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this code:

```
SELECT
      p1.DENUMIRE,
      clase.CLASA,
      furnizori.NUME_J,
      furnizori.NUME_F
FROM produse
JOIN produse p1 ON p1.ID_CLASA = clase.ID
JOIN produse p2 ON p2.ID_FURNIZOR = furnizori.ID
LIMIT 1000
;
```

The code it returned error #1054: Unknown column 'clase.CLASA' in 'field list'.

I modified the code in:

```
SELECT
      p1.DENUMIRE,
      clase.CLASA,
      furnizori.NUME_J,
      furnizori.NUME_F
FROM clase
JOIN produse p1 ON p1.ID_CLASA = clase.ID
JOIN produse p2 ON p2.ID_FURNIZOR = furnizori.ID
LIMIT 1000
;
```

The code it returned error #1054: Unknown column 'furnizori.NUME_J' in 'field list'.

I modified the code in:

```
SELECT
      p1.DENUMIRE,
      clase.CLASA,
      furnizori.NUME_J,
      furnizori.NUME_F
FROM furnizori
JOIN produse p1 ON p1.ID_CLASA = clase.ID
JOIN produse p2 ON p2.ID_FURNIZOR = furnizori.ID
LIMIT 1000
;
```

The code it returned error #1054: Unknown column 'clase.CLASA' in 'field list'.

I modified the code in:

```
SELECT
      p1.DENUMIRE,
      clase.CLASA,
      furnizori.NUME_J,
      furnizori.NUME_F
FROM produse, clase, furnizori
JOIN produse p1 ON p1.ID_CLASA = clase.ID
JOIN produse p2 ON p2.ID_FURNIZOR = furnizori.ID
LIMIT 1000
;
```

The code it returned error #1054: Unknown column 'clase.ID' in 'field list'.

Comment: Which Database engine? Microsoft, Oracle, mysql ?

Comment: Your tries look to me like you are randomly changing things. What result do you want at all?

Comment: Database is in mysql

Comment: What tables are you trying to join? Are they all aliases of the same table? Can you give sample data in tables?

Answer (score 0):

if you have one table and need do self join, then you need add and use right 
aliases:

```
SELECT
  produse.DENUMIRE,
  clase.CLASA,
  furnizori.NUME_J,
  furnizori.NUME_F
FROM produse
JOIN produse as clase ON clase.ID_CLASA = produse.ID
JOIN produse as furnizori ON furnizori.ID_FURNIZOR = produse.ID
LIMIT 1000;
```

so, if you have 3 tables, you don't need use aliases

```
SELECT
  produse.DENUMIRE,
  clase.CLASA,
  furnizori.NUME_J,
  furnizori.NUME_F
FROM produse
JOIN clase ON produse.ID_CLASA = clase.ID
JOIN furnizori ON produse.ID_FURNIZOR = furnizori.ID
LIMIT 1000;
```

Comment: Returned error #1054: Unknown column 'clase.CLASA' in 'field list'.

Comment: what tables you have?

Comment: produse, clase and furnizori

Comment: did it helped? did you find another solution?

Comment: I have not found a solution

Comment: Please give more information about your tables and data or FK, you can list tables and fields, this will be helpful to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem:

```html
SELECT
      produse.DENUMIRE,
      clase.CLASA,
      furnizori.NUME_J,
      furnizori.NUME_F
FROM clase
JOIN produse ON produse.ID_CLASA = clase.ID
JOIN furnizori ON produse.ID_FURNIZOR = furnizori.ID
LIMIT 1000;
```